# How to Reindex Removed URL in Google WebMaster

Tags: google, google-search-console

I requested from Google Webmaster to remove an URL called `example.com/demo` some months ago and the URL was removed from the search engine and now the status is expired. 
Today I want to reindex the demo page  and have it appear in the search engine again but Google Webmaster is showing "301 Redurect html is corrupted" in the index request

.

Comment: Google does NOT index 301 redirect URLS... it indexes the page that it redirects too. Remove the redirect or use the fetch on the result URL.

Comment: The removed site is effectively a new site, therefore, this is duplicate since it involves the same process.

Comment: this question is not a duplicate. I actually search for this question and did not find any answer.  The page was indexed before and have it deindexed a couple of months ago and want to have it reindex, the problem is it is showing 301 redirect on the request index result saying html is corrupted

Comment: It's duplicate in the current format that you have provided. As previously mentioned the error you have is related to 301 redirecting which has nothing to do with GSC or its indexing process apart from the fact if your server or code is responding incorrectly then some users and most bots will have issues browsing your site. To fix the issue you can research 301 redirect issues on Pro Webmasters or if you want to get more information on the issue then do a 'CURL' and a Google Fetch and Render, since you have done either or failed to provide this to the community, not much help can be provided.

Comment: 301 is not created or done on the website but by google webmaster upon requesting it to be removed from google search. I am not asking why it is not index because it was index , request to be removed and reindex but returning 301 on web master

Comment: Going in circles, please provide CURL and Google Fetch Render status.